# Get information from a .txt file with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, node.js

Whats the best method to find and rewrite a file, like, I have a list of names in .txt, like this:

```
John    Huynh   male    65  10/6/1951   JohnJHuynh@rhyta.com    New Zealand Poraiti 4112
Abigail Yates   female  39  4/18/1977   AbigailYates@superrito.com  Canada  Toronto M5G 2J5
Florence    Urbaniak    female  63  12/14/1952  FlorenceJUrbaniak@gustr.com Canada  Toronto M5H 2S8
Adrian  Bibby   male    70  9/24/1946   AdrianKBibby@rhyta.com  Italy   Trivigliano 03010
Jeremy  Roach   male    65  1/17/1951   JeremyLRoach@gustr.com  Italy   Mercenasco  10010
```

I separate this with a tab to look better here and fake the information, obviously, but in the .txt theres spaces, and I have lists with like, 5000 people and infos, so, my idea is, create a database with all this, because I need just some information of all these, like Name, Surname and Mail, but I don't know if there's a method to snipe and separate informations to put in a database. I think in use PHP + Javascript, is this a good or bad start?

Comment: Is this for a single import? Or is this process going to be happening intermittently? Is it a "known" file, or a file that is, e.g. uploaded by users. You're probably looking for [fgetcsv](http://php.net/fgetcsv) setting the delimiter as a tab.

Comment: It's running intermittenly from a known file, but this file keep refreshing every 5 minutes @JonStirling

Comment: So a cron job. You can do this with only PHP if you wish using the function mentioned above to parse the CSV into PHP arrays that you can then use to insert rows into a database. Of course I'm pretty sure you could do similar with the likes of node.js (not sure about angular though) or other languages.

Comment: why can't you change where it gets written to file and write it to database instead?

Comment: My suggestion is to directly import from a cronjob using a shell scrip that invokes your database CLI, asuming you're working on Unix-like system.